# Could the contents of a bottle affect the surface temperature of that bottle?

Tags: temperature

e.g.

If I had two bottles one with Vodka in and one with Water in (both the same glass bottle spec/size)

If I then put these two bottles in a freezer would the surface temperature of the bottle be the same or different?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long time both will cool to the temperature of the freezer, the time taken will depend on the specific heats of water v vodka (which I suspect are similar).  This is a consequence of the second law of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

While the contents of the bottle will not affect its temperature, the different heat capacities and thermal conductivities of the fluid inside can affect how cold the bottle feels to the touch. Some cold things transfer heat quickly, and these feel very cold, while others transfer heat more slowly, and only feel moderately cold at the same temperature. If you felt that the vodka is warmer, this is probably the reason.